# Can I speed up apache superset queries by setting Presto between superset and mysql?

Tags: apache-superset

I'm a fresh data engineer and i recently deployed my own apache superset for BI team and the tool access data from mysql. The problem is mysql data have some tables which are used to save raw log so it's making some timed out queries in the superset.

Can I speed up apache superset queries by setting Presto between superset and mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, if querying the raw data is slow you'll probably benefit of some tool to speed querying the database, being it Presto (I haven't worked with it, so I only have a very big picture idea of what it does) or building aggregate tables with some kind of ETL/ELT tool to query pre-summarize data instead of the raw data directly, or adding indexes, partitions, views to the database to improve performance on that side.